# "s:Client: Not Allowed List" error when running Loket.nl query

Tags: invantive-sql, loket-nl

For one customer site, the following query:

```
select /*+ ods(false) */ *
from   Werkgevers@loket wgr
join   PersonenPerWerkgever(wgr.entryid)@loket psn
join   WerknemerVerloningsrunsPerPersoon(wgr.entryid)@loket wvn
```

returns an error with message code "s:Client" and text "Not Allowed List".

I seem unable to find any documentation on this loket.nl error with Invantive SQL. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is typically caused by missing privileges. The text is not very well formulated, but you will have to live with it since Loket is focusing on adding a new REST-based API platform.

Make sure your user has sufficient privileges.